# migrate i386 qemu VM to amd64 VM host

Tags: kvm, qemu

I have an `i386` qemu VM:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 3
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.1.2
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x1
cpu MHz         : 3092.972
cache size      : 4096 KB
fdiv_bug        : no
hlt_bug         : no
f00f_bug        : no
coma_bug        : no
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 4
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep pge cmov mmx fxsr sse sse2 up pni popcnt hypervisor
bogomips        : 6185.94
clflush size    : 32
cache_alignment : 32
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```

..which runs in `i386` VM-host:

```
root@VM-host:~# uname -a
Linux VM-host 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 i686 GNU/Linux
root@VM-host:~#
```

It is started with `qemu --enable-kvm -daemonize ...` command. I would like to migrate this VM to a new VM host with `amd64` architecture. Is this possible? Are there any performance penalties?

Comment: Well at least the [the FAQ](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#Can_KVM_run_a_32-bit_guest_on_a_64-bit_host.3F_What_about_PAE.3F) says it should be ok: "KVM supports 32-bit guests on 64-bit hosts, and any combination of PAE and non-PAE guests and hosts. The only unsupported combination is a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit host." AFAIK 64-bit x86 processors should be able to run 32-bit programs as well as 32-bit processors can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely run 32Bit guests on 64Bit KVM Hypervisors, and on most -if not all- other recent (popular) hypervisors.

I, and many other people here run many of these installations. There are no significant performance penalties that I perceive. Using virt-io or not makes makes a much more drastic difference.

But if i can, I use 64Bit guests too. You should really evaluate that option too, because 64Bit mode comes with some nice goodies, and no real disadvantages these days.

@ilkkachu correctly points out, that this fact is also mentioned in the fine [FAQ](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#Can_KVM_run_a_32-bit_guest_on_a_64-bit_host.3F_What_about_PAE.3F).